# how to Dismiss Keyboard if we touch other area outside UITextView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have UITextView ***inside static table view***, I want to remove the keyboard if the user touch other area **outside the textView**

usually I can this lines of code to remove the keyboard, but i don't know why, after adding placeholder in the textview, it doesn't work. I suspect because it is inside table view static

```
extension CheckinDetailTVC {

    // to remove keyboard if we touch other area
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }

}
```

I also have tried another solution in stackoverflow but no one work in me, like add gesture recognizer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGestureReconizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureReconizer)
}

func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

or add function in TextViewDelegate, but it also doesn't work

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
```

here is the screenshot of my UI

[image]

here is the simplified code I Use in the view controller

```
class CheckinDetailTVC: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var noteTextView: UITextView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // to put placeholder for UITextView
        noteTextView.delegate = self
        noteTextView.text = "Write your note in here ..."
        noteTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        noteTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        noteTextView.selectedTextRange = noteTextView.textRange(from: noteTextView.beginningOfDocument, to: noteTextView.beginningOfDocument)



    }



}




extension CheckinDetailTVC : UITextViewDelegate {

// add placeholder for textView

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        let currentText:String = textView.text
        let updatedText = (currentText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

        if updatedText.isEmpty {

            textView.text = "Write your note in here ..."
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

            textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)

            return false
        }

        else if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray && !text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }

        return true
    }

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if self.view.window != nil {
            if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
                textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.beginningOfDocument)
            }
        }
    }

}




extension CheckinDetailTVC {

    // usually i can use this code to remove keyboard if we touch other area
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(false)
    }

}
```

what went wrong in here?

Comment: are you tried the `noteTextView.resignFirstResponder()` inside the method `func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {`

Comment: oh my God, newbie mistake, I forgot to edit the view to noteTextView. Thank you very much Anbu Karthik

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**option 1**

Without blocking the UI add the `cancelsTouchesInView` 
 for your gesture `

```
let tapGestureReconizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
tapGestureReconizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureReconizer)
```

**option 2**

else handle the resign in multiple ways

```
func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
 view.endEditing(true)
 // or use 
 noteTextView.resignFirstResponder()
 // or use
 view.super().endEditing(true)
 // or use
 view.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
}
```

Comment: which one used for dismiss the keyboard

Answer (score 8):

As they mentioned above using `UITapGestureRecognizer` would make the trick

```
extension UIViewController {

    @objc func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:    #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

And then in the `viewDidLoad`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add gestures to dismiss the keyboard with a touch or swipe. Create an object of touch gesture and add an action method that causes the view to resign from the status of first responder:

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func DismissKeyboard(){
//Causes the view to resign from the status of first responder.
view.endEditing(true)
}
```